# How can I describe for accessibility inspector the action of tapping a UIImageView?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, accessibility

I have a `UIImageView` that has a `UITapGestureRecognizer` which is set as a button in the property
`accessibilityTraits`. I want to describe the content description of the action when it's tapped for people with vision deficits.

How can i achieve this?

I've tried this:

```
if let desc = model.rightIconActionDescription {
   let action = UIAccessibilityCustomAction(name: desc, target: self, selector: #selector(executeAction))
   let actionsArray = [action]
   self.rightIcon.accessibilityCustomActions = actionsArray
}
```

and I've also tried to pass text value to imageView.accessibilityHint.
None of this worked.

I expect to listen the description of the action when the image view is tapped (in my case, a simple print)

Comment: Does the answer below meet your needs or not?

Comment: @HangarRash i finally found an alternative solution, using another property, the accessibilityValue. So I could'nt try that one

Answer (score 1):

I would post the `announcement` notification inside your tap gesture handler. Something like the following should work:

```
// Your tap gesture handler
@objc func tapHandler(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture.state == .ended {
        // Your code to handle the tap here

        // Make announcement for voice over users
        if UIAccessibility.isVoiceOverRunning {
            let message = "Some description of the image"
            UIAccessibility.post(notification: .announcement, argument: message as NSString)
        }
    }
}
```

Using `UIAccessibilityCustomAction` is useful when a view has focus and the user swipes up or down to hear the list of possible actions. That is not what you want in this case.